# How can I pause a loop until I get a users input?

Tags: java, loops

I am a beginner at Java and I am making a fun project for myself to learn more about java, I plan on randomizing videos from a preset list and displaying it to the user.

I am having trouble stopping the loop. Once you type in the kind of video you want to watch the program automatically re-loops, but i want it to ask you if you want to watch another video before relooping. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class YoutubeGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int randomstring = 0;

        for ( ; ; ) {

            System.out.println("\n ---------Youtube Video Generator 0.001 BETA------------------ \n");

            System.out.println("\n ********* DISCLAIMER: WARNING - This program may direct you to violent, disturbing content, and/or vulgar language and is intended for a MATURE person only. ********* \n \n");

        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

        System.out.println("What kind of video from the list would you like to watch? \n");

        System.out.println("Cute \n" + "Funny \n" + "WTF \n" + "Interesting \n" + "Documentary \n");

        System.out.print("I want to watch: ");

        String userString = scan.next();

    Random rand = new Random();



if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("cute")){

    String cute1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdCVijVT7Wk";
    String cute2 = "http://youtu.be/-XCvPptsfhI?t=7s";
    String cute3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nkEPsSsH68";
    String cute4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ-bJFVJ2P0";
    String cute5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=argCvDpk_KQ";

    System.out.println("Here's a cute video you can watch: " +cute5) ; 
}
if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("funny")){  

    System.out.println("Here's a funny you can watch:"); 

    String funny1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I59MgGlh2Mg";
    String funny2 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKMNKS-9ugY";
    String funny3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qKmWfED8mA";
    String funny4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDFQYKPsVOQ";
    String funny5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebv51QNm2Bk";

}

if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("wtf")){  

    System.out.println("Here's a WTF video you can watch:");  

    String wtf1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfKIoSv2YEg";
    String wtf2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcGvN0iBA5s";
    String wtf3 = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxnyqvejPjI&feature=youtu.be&t=1m37s";
    String wtf4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10NJnT6-sSE";
    String wtf5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQeyjgSUlrk";

    }

if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("interesting")){  

    System.out.println("Here's an interesting video you can watch:");

    String int1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYwRMEomJMM";
    String int2 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PmYItnlY5M&feature=youtu.be&t=32s";
    String int3 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgmnIJF07kg";
    String int4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUcoiJgEyag";
    String int5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BePoF4PrwHs";
}
if(userString.equalsIgnoreCase("documentary")){  

    System.out.println("Here's a space video you can watch: ");  

    String doc1 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wS_WlzdOc_A";
    String doc22 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8n0SkIGARuo";
    String doc33 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LaSD8oFBZE";
    String doc4= "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvfLdg2DN18";
    String doc5 = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8af0QPhJ22s&hd=1";
    }  
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Its not clear exactly what you're trying to do, but I think that it may become clearer to you if you separate the chunk of code that handles the user's input from the main input loop. Make it a separate method. Then the loop will be simple: get input, process, repeat.

Comment: Do not say `new Scanner(System.in)` inside a loop.  Do that only once.

Comment: place the for-loop line after this line `Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following code right before the closing brace of your loop:

```
System.out.println("Do you want to watch another video? Enter yes or no");
String decision = scan.next();
if (decision.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))
    break;
```

Comment: @codeacode you're welcome. One more small hint: `while (true) {...}` is perhaps more readable code than `for ( ; ; ) {...}`, but both loops do exactly the same thing. Also, you might eventually look into GUI creation to make your application more user-friendly and for ease of input validation: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm